# Почему не работает код удаления номера телефона контакта?

Tags: java, android

Необходимо реализовать удаление номера телефона из контакта. Мне посоветовали код, по словам автора кода у него всё работало. Однако у меня код эффекта не даёт, ошибок тоже нету.

```
private final String queryPhone = ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID + 
    "=? AND " +
    ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.MIMETYPE + 
    "='" + 
    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + 
    "'" + 
    " AND ";
private final String queryByNumber = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER + "=?";

public void removePhoneByNumber(Long contactId, String phoneNumber) {
    ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> os = new ArrayList();
    String[] phoneArgs = new String[] {
        String.valueOf(contactId), phoneNumber
    };
    os.add(ContentProviderOperation.newDelete(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
            .withSelection(queryPhone + queryByNumber, phoneArgs)
            .build());
    try {
        getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, os);
    }
    catch (RemoteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (OperationApplicationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

В манифесте разрешения на чтение и запись контактов прописаны. В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: На какой версии Android не работает? В рантайме [разрешения](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/requesting.html) запрашиваете?

Comment: `String.valueOf(contactId), phoneNumber` - точно корректные данные?

Comment: Данные корректные, версия Android - 5.0

Answer (score 0):

Есть подозрение, что я нашёл возможную причину вашей проблему. Для этого пришлось перелопатить немало англоязычных форумов и поставить экспериментов. В английском сегменте SO натолкнулся на вопрос с похоже на вашу проблемой. [В ответе написано](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27485544/1911548), что именно в Lollipop к запросу нужно добавлять не только номер телефона, но и его тип:

```
private final String queryPhone = Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID + "=? AND "
       + Data.MIMETYPE + "='" + Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "'";
private final String queryByType = " AND " + Phone.TYPE + "=?";
private final String queryByNumber = " AND "
        + "replace(replace(replace(" + Phone.NUMBER + ", ' ', ''), '-', ''), '+', '')"
        + "=?";

public void removePhone(Long contactId, int phoneType, String phoneNumber) {
    ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList();
    String[] phoneArgs = new String[] {String.valueOf(contactId),
            String.valueOf(phoneType),
            phoneNumber.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "")};
    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newDelete(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
            .withSelection(queryPhone + queryByType + queryByNumber, phoneArgs)
            .build());
    try {
        getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
    }
    catch (RemoteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (OperationApplicationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

И в обработчике клика

```
removePhone(1L, Phone.TYPE_MOBILE, "+71234567890");
```

Comment: Выводит ошибку:
`Cannot bind argument at index 3 because the index is out of range.  The statement has 2 parameters.`
При этом все три аргумента имеют значения, проверял.

Comment: Проверьте константы с запросом.

Comment: Константы тоже обновил, все три знака вопроса на месте. Типы данных совпадают, но есть сомнения насчёт `phoneNumber.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "")};`.

Comment: Пусть для простоты будет просто `phoneNumber` и в константе `queryByNumber` тогда просто `" AND " + Phone.NUMBER + "=?"`. Но тогда в `phoneNumber` телефон должен быть ровно в том формате, в котором отображается в контакте.

Comment: А если я беру номер телефона и без форматирования вставляю его в EditText, его формат будет считаться идентичным формату в базе?

Comment: Мой телефон, как и эмуляторы, сохраняет телефон в формате '+7 123 456-78-90', если передать в `phoneNumber` что-то отличное от этой строки, он не удалится.

Comment: Мой сохраняет номера в том формате, в котором напишу. Если это `5553535` - так и отображает, если `331 02 62` - отображает с пробелами.
Упростил как вы сказали - ошибка та же. А возможно узнать какой именно аргумент он теряет?

Comment: Вот поэтому я добавил `replace()` в запрос и `.replaceAll()` к `phoneNumber`, чтобы быть независимым от формата. Я бы рекомендовал вывести в лог `queryPhone + queryByType + queryByNumber` и `Arrays.toString(phoneArgs)` и внимательно их сравнить.

Comment: Вывело вот это: 
    `W/Query: raw_contact_id=? AND mimetype='vnd.android.cursor.item/phone_v2' AND data2=? AND replace(replace(replace(data1, ' ', ''), '-', ''), '+', '')=?`
    `W/Array: [35, 2, 375336017110]`

Comment: Мистика. Могу предложить только отправить архив с проектом мне, я проверю у себя.

Comment: Как вам скинуть?